# How to pivot and rename columns based on several grouped columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot, rename

I am getting trouble using `agg` function and renaming results properly. So far I  have made the table of the following format.

| sheet | equipment | chamber | time | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | E1 | C1 | 1 | 11 | 21 |
| a | E1 | C1 | 2 | 12 | 22 |
| a | E1 | C1 | 3 | 13 | 23 |
| b | E1 | C1 | 1 | 14 | 24 |
| b | E1 | C1 | 2 | 15 | 25 |
| b | E1 | C1 | 3 | 16 | 26 |

I would like to create a statistical table like this:

| sheet | E1_C1_value1_mean | E1_C1_value1_min | E1_C1_value1_max | E1_C1_value2_mean | E1_C1_value2_min | E1_C1_value2_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 12 | 11 | 13 | 22 | 21 | 23 |
| b | 15 | 14 | 16 | 25 | 24 | 26 |

Which I would like to `groupBy` "sheet", "equipment", "chamber" to aggregate mean, min, max values.
I also need to rename column by the rule: equip + chamber + aggregation function.
There are multiple "equipment" names and "chamber" names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `pivot` in spark only accept single column, therefore you have to concat the column which you want to pivot:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 1, 11, 21),
        ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 2, 12, 22),
        ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 3, 13, 23),
        ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 1, 14, 24),
        ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 2, 15, 25),
        ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 3, 16, 26),
    ],
    schema=['sheet', 'equipment', 'chamber', 'time', 'value1', 'value2']
)

df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+
|sheet|equipment|chamber|time|value1|value2|
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+
|a    |E1       |C1     |1   |11    |21    |
|a    |E1       |C1     |2   |12    |22    |
|a    |E1       |C1     |3   |13    |23    |
|b    |E1       |C1     |1   |14    |24    |
|b    |E1       |C1     |2   |15    |25    |
|b    |E1       |C1     |3   |16    |26    |
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+
```

Assume there are lots of columns that you want to do the aggregation, you can use a loop to create and prevent the bulky coding:

```
aggregation = []
for col in df.columns[-2:]:
    aggregation += [func.min(col).alias(f"{col}_min"), func.max(col).alias(f"{col}_max"), func.avg(col).alias(f"{col}_mean")]


df.withColumn('new_col', func.concat_ws('_', func.col('equipment'), func.col('chamber')))\
    .groupby('sheet')\
    .pivot('new_col')\
    .agg(*aggregation)\
    .orderBy('sheet')\
    .show(100, False)
+-----+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|sheet|E1_C1_value1_min|E1_C1_value1_max|E1_C1_value1_mean|E1_C1_value2_min|E1_C1_value2_max|E1_C1_value2_mean|
+-----+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|a    |11              |13              |12.0             |21              |23              |22.0             |
|b    |14              |16              |15.0             |24              |26              |25.0             |
+-----+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: It works perfectly! The expression of aggregation list is what I am looking for. I learn the way use loop and concat_ws in spark. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a column out of those which you want to pivot.
Then, pivot and aggregate as usual.

Input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 'E1', 'C1', 1, 11, 21),
     ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 2, 12, 22),
     ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 3, 13, 23),
     ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 1, 14, 24),
     ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 2, 15, 25),
     ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 3, 16, 26)],
    ['sheet', 'equipment', 'chamber', 'time', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

Script:

```py
df = df.withColumn('_temp', F.concat_ws('_', 'equipment', 'chamber'))
df = (df
    .groupBy('sheet')
    .pivot('_temp')
    .agg(
        F.mean('value1').alias('value1_mean'),
        F.min('value1').alias('value1_min'),
        F.max('value1').alias('value1_max'),
        F.mean('value2').alias('value2_mean'),
        F.min('value2').alias('value2_min'),
        F.max('value2').alias('value2_max'),
    )
)

df.show()
# +-----+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
# |sheet|E1_C1_value1_mean|E1_C1_value1_min|E1_C1_value1_max|E1_C1_value2_mean|E1_C1_value2_min|E1_C1_value2_max|
# +-----+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
# |    b|             15.0|              14|              16|             25.0|              24|              26|
# |    a|             12.0|              11|              13|             22.0|              21|              23|
# +-----+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I am looking for a expression that could directly work to all columns, like value1, value2 ... value1000. Also thank you help me clarify my problem. Indeed the numerous values, equipment and chamber are keys to my mission. Thank you.